# How do I keep my video player working in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

When I use the video_player plugin, I use the Navigator.push function to go to another screen where I push a button to display the video. Once the video is over, I push the back button. If I activate the Navigator.push function again and push the button to display the video, no visual is shown and only the audio is played. Can someone tell me what is going on and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found out that the issue was that I needed to call setState before I could display the video the second time.